# $-1 = 4\cos(t^2) - \sin(t^2)\cos(t^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$-1 = 4\cos(t^2) - \sin(t^2)\cos(t^2)$$
I was solving a problem and I arrived to this. I am wondering if there is a way to solve for $t\in (1,2)$ without using a computer.

Answer (score 0):

### It's not pretty.

You can try to divide both sides by $\cos^2 t^2$, and you get:
$$-\sec^2t^2=4\sec t^2-\tan t^2$$
Rewrite $\sec^2t^2$ as $\tan^2t^2+1$ and isolate $4\sec t^2$, you get:
$$-\tan^2t^2-1+\tan t^2=4\sec t^2$$
Square both sides and you get:
$$\tan ^4\left(t^2\right)-2 \tan ^3\left(t^2\right)+3 \tan ^2\left(t^2\right)-2 \tan \left(t^2\right)+1=16\sec^2 t^2\\
\tan ^4\left(t^2\right)-2 \tan ^3\left(t^2\right)-13 \tan ^2\left(t^2\right)-2 \tan \left(t^2\right)-15=0$$
You can then try solve the quartic equation in $\tan t^2$.

---

Although, you can use numerical methods to solve this:

Using NR you get this recurrence relation for $f(\text{t})\text{:=}4 \cos \left(t^2\right)-\sin \left(t^2\right) \cos \left(t^2\right)+1$:
$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n)}\iff \frac{1-\left(\sin \left(t_n^2\right)-4\right) \cos \left(t_n^2\right)}{2 t_n \left(4 \sin \left(t_n^2\right)+\cos \left(2 t_n^2\right)\right)}+t_n$$

After sufficient iterations you get solutions as:
$$\text{for}\,\, t_0=0.8\Rightarrow t=1.3799511968833622\\
\text{for}\,\, t_0=0.6\Rightarrow t=2.1237221862028157\\
\text{for}\,\, t_0=0.5\Rightarrow t=2.861372155620343\\
\vdots$$

You can find other $t$ in $[1,2]$, but I believe only one exists.

Comment: The OP is asking to solve for $t\in(1,2)$, not $t\in[1,2]$. However, regarding the first half, of your answer, that seems pretty good.

Comment: @user477343 Oh, what is meant by $t\in(1,2)$?

Comment: $(m, n)$ is an open interval and $[m, n]$ is a closed interval such that $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ are the *endpoints* of both intervals. The former interval is an *exclusive* range, so it does not include $m$ and $n$. The latter interval is an *inclusive* range, so it does include $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @user477343 Sorry, I still do not understand. How would a numerical solution not be an answer?